# Using 5 buttons to launch one dialogbox

Tags: java, android

I have a layout that contains 5 buttons which must display one particular dialogbox on clicking any of the buttons. 
I assigned one **id** to the buttons and set an **onClick** listener to it. 
surprisingly, only the first button on the layout displays the dialogbox and others do not. 
how can i make all of them to display that particular dialog because i don't want to create different dialog for each button.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code to help better understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a class to assign the attribute. Multiple buttons cannot have the same id.

Comment: i don't know about using class to assign the attribute.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Can you please share the code. I would need to make some necessary modifications in it.